# How to manually trigger AsyncSnapshot error with FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, future, snapshot

I'm tring to manually trigger `snapshot.hasError` when a future is called and a response is gotten.
For instance I have a future

```
   Future<dynamic> getJson() {
     Dio dio = Dio();
     var response = dio.get("https://www.jsononline.com/posts?id=9999");
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       return response;
     } else {
      // return AsyncSnapshot error
      }
    }
```

I've tried `return AsyncSnapshot.withError(ConnectionState.done, "An error occurred");` but in the FutureBuilder `snapshot.hasError` is still null, instead it goes to `snapshot.data`.

I want to be able to trigger the error if I get a `404` message for instance.

Comment: use `Future<T>.error()` constructor then (or simply `throw yourError`)

Comment: @pskink `Future<T>.error()` worked. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Return**

```
return Future.error("Error Info", StackTrace.fromString("StackTrace Error message"));
```